# ¿Cuándo se usa "sino" y cuándo "si no"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, conjunciones

Hace poco he leído un libro donde se empleaba el ***sino***. Al principio pensaba que era un error de ortografía, pero me resulta un poco extraño que se equivocaron en poner *sino* y no separado *si no*.

¿Qué es *sino*? ¿Cuándo se usa? ¿Cuándo debe utilizarse *si no*?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- "Si no" = if + negative

> **Si no** coges el paraguas, te mojarás. <sub>If you don't take your umbrella with you, you'll get wet</sub>

- [Sino](http://dle.rae.es/sino)"= similar to "but" ("instead" in a negative way; "except", "only")

> No llegan mañana, **sino** el martes. <sub>They don't arrive tomorrow, but on Tuesday</sub>

Este [vídeo](http://losfilologos.com/portal/index.php/linguistica/628-fundeu-bbva-como-diferenciar-si-no-y-sino) puede ser de ayuda

Comment: Sin embargo, hay múltiples ejemplos de "si no" incorrectamente escrito como "sino".

Comment: Otra cosa: "sino" es también un sustantivo que significa "destino" o "hado" (fate, en inglés).

Comment: @MikMik, no estoy seguro pero me parece que la academia ha empezado a admitir _sino_ escrito como _si no_ (o viceversa). Aunque no sea incorrecto, a mí me parece horrible, de todas formas.

Answer (score 3):

[@Zeravala's answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/3401/1674) is good, but I'd add a few things.

When I was learning Spanish, I decided that the best translation of *sino* was most often "but rather."  *No leí el libro de Bioy Casares sino el de Borges*  translates to "I didn't read Bioy Casares' book but rather Borges'."  Of course sometimes "but" works better, sometimes "rather" or "instead", and sometimes something quite different works best, which brings me to my next point.

*Sino* can mean something along the lines of "do anything but" such as in *no puedo sino reír* which you might translate as "I can't do anything but laugh."  This second usage is far less common than the first, but as it will turn up from time to time, you should be prepared to recognize it.

Finally, to reiterate what @MikMik said, you should also be prepared to see what would properly be written as *si no* squashed together.  Many people are sloppy.

Answer (score 3):

Usando el mismo ejemplo antes citado supongamos que alguien dice *Mañana llegan del viaje* pero la realidad es que llegan el martes, si yo quiero corregir y digo solamente *No llegan mañana* entonces estaría diciendo que no llegan ni mañana ni nunca. Por esa razón es necesario decir *No llegan mañana pero sí llegan el martes* y esto se abrevia como *No llegan mañana sino el martes*.