# Usage of pero vs sino

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, conjunciones

I am new to Spanish and was wondering when I need to use 'pero' in a sentence vs 'sino'.

I have seen both these words used in sentences and I am confused on when to use which.

Comment: Please add at least an example of a sentence showing your doubt ("pero" has a few possible meanings, one of them was "sino", but it is now obsolete http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=pero)

Comment: Here you go.. These are examples used on my Spanish learning program.

Él tiene una camisa pero no es roja.

No son minutos, sino horas.

Comment: Ok. Let's play a game: "El no tiene una camisa, sino una remera" -> "El tiene una camisa, pero no una remera".

Comment: @belisarius "Yo no se como responder a esta pregunta sino hacer juegos con ella."

Comment: @AlfredoOsorio Bueno, si no sabes como reponder, aquí va una ayuda http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=sino :)

Comment: Related: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3400/12

Comment: @belisarius I'm not sure how it works.. Do you mean that if the 'no' appears in the first part of the sentence, then we should use sino and if 'no' appears in the second part of the sentence, we should use pero?

Comment: @slayernoah Quoting Leon's answer: _""Sino" follows a negative assertion, to provide instead the "right" (positive) alternative. ("Not that, but this" . "No aquello, sino esto"). "But" just joins two sentences that are sowewhat opposite."_

Comment: @belisarius Thanks! Sorry I didn't see all the other answers below!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The confusion for English speakers can arise because "pero" and "sino" both translate to "but".

> Él tiene una camisa, **pero** no es roja.
>    He has a shirt, **but** it's not red.
>
> No he venido a ser servido, **sino** a servir.
>   I haven't come to be served, **but** to serve.

Some differences:

- "Sino" follows a negative assertion, to provide **instead** the "right" (positive) alternative. ("Not that, but this" . "No aquello, sino esto"). "Pero" just joins two sentences that are sowewhat opposite.
- "Sino" can often be translated as **instead** or **rather** (where these words function as "but").
- "Sino" is a more connected conjuntion: the words that follow complete the sentence, it's syntactically related and it's contruction depends on the opening. By contrast, "Pero" opens a new independent clause. See the above examples. Quick rule: only before a "pero" we can replace the comma by a semicolon or a period ("Él tiene una camisa. Pero no es roja.").

[More info](http://spanish.about.com/od/conjunctions/a/sino_pero.htm)

Comment: So would "I haven't come to be served, but I have come to serve" use *pero* or *sino*? It doesn't fit your rule that the second clause is independent, but it fits the other rules.

Comment: I don't see it that way. The correct/natural form is "I haven't come to be served, but to serve". In any case, the second part, what follows the "but", mimics syntantically the first (just toggling the negative to a positive), it's not an independent construct.

Comment: I wonder if you didn't understand my question. Sometimes, for stylistic reasons or emphasis, for example, someone would repeat the entire phrase.  I'm asking if *sino* would still be appropriate then?  Another English example might be, "I don't like cats, but I do like dogs."  Is *sino* still appropriate, or would *pero* be used, since there is an independent clause?

Comment: @Flimzy: If the clause is independent, "pero" is the correct one; "No me gustan los gatos; pero me gustan los perros".

Answer (score 8):

[**Sino**](http://dle.rae.es/sino) is a conjunction, and is used exactly the same as **pero**, except that it is used in cases of negation.  It can be thought to roughly translate to the English terms **however** or **rather**, but is more specific than the English terms.

To use **sino**, there must be a negative word (such as **no**) preceding the conjunction

Examples:

1. > I don't want to go to the movies, rather/however/but I want to go home.
   >
   > No quiero ir al cine, **sino** quiero ir a mi casa.
2. > The dog is not brown, but/however/rather black.
   >
   > El perro no es marrón, **sino** negro.

Comment: @slayernoah: No problem, and we're glad you're here! Welcome to Spanish.SE.

Answer (score 3):

The word "pero" is used to expand or oppose a concept. 
For example:
Puedes dormir tarde **"pero"** el otro dia tendrás sueño.
El puede venir **"pero"** debe traer algo.


In case of word **"sino"**, is used to oppose a concept to another previous negative.
For Example:
No es que no quiera que venga **"sino"** que venga otro día.
No lo hizo ella **"sino"** que lo hizo el.

Well, I hope this help you.

Answer (score 2):

*Sino* is an elegant way to provide a [non-obvious alternative to a negative statement](http://itsnachotime.com/blog/sino-mas-bien), without having to start a new sentence.

To avoid confusing it with *pero*, try replacing it with *although*–if it works, it's *pero*; otherwise, it's *sino*.

> — Me apetecía verte hoy, **pero** hasta mañana no puedo.
>
> "I felt like seeing you today, (but/although) until tomorrow, I can't."
>
> — Pues yo no contaba con verte hoy, **sino** mañana, así que perfecto.
>
> "(Well) I wasn't counting on seeing you today, (but/I was counting on seeing you) tomorrow, so that's perfect."

Comment: Nice answer! Welcome to [spanish.se] :)